# Chat con Socket.io no emite mas de un mensaje

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Estoy realizando una pequeña app de chat, tengo dos campos, uno el username y el otro es el mensaje, junto con un botón de Enviar. Cuando emito un mensaje se agrega a un div, pero al querer enviar otro mensaje, este no se emite, ni siquiera en consola
Esta parte es de la del server donde emito

```
  socket.on('chat:message',(data)=>{
    io.sockets.emit('chat:message',data)
  })
```

Aca mapeo en el front

```
socket.on('chat:message',(data)=>{
  output.innerHTML +=
  `<p>
    <strong>${data.username}</strong>: ${data.message}
  </p>`
})
```

[image: Imagen del chat y el codigo]

Genero un evento al presionar el botón

```
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  socket.emit('chat:message',{
    message:message.value,
    username:username.value
  })
})
```